# How do I find the top-most picbox in a List<picturebox> within Bounds.Contains(e.Location)?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I've come across a problem in my panel1_MouseMove event. I have 3 pictureboxes inside List pBoxes, which are all drawn to the panel & the picturebox controls are set to Visible = false.

The problem is that when there are overlapping images, when I click one image it may select the pictureBox Behind it. Like so[image]

Here is the code:

```
    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
if (picturebox1.Bounds.Contains(e.Location) && !picturebox1.Visible)
{
picturebox1.Show();
picturebox2.Hide();
picturebox3.Hide();
}
if (picturebox2.Bounds.Contains(e.Location) && !picturebox2.Visible)
{
picturebox1.Hide();
picturebox2.Show();
picturebox3.Hide();
}
if (picturebox3.Bounds.Contains(e.Location) && !picturebox3.Visible)
{
picturebox1.Hide();
picturebox2.Hide();
picturebox3.Show();
}
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated, and yes I have to use Bounds.Contains for my particular application. Another way to look at my question is that I am trying to create a pictureBox1__MouseClick event without a Visible control.

Comment: how is the layout of the picturebox control placed on your form designer..??

Comment: Just how a normal picturebox control is placed, I just have it set to invisible and the only way to make it visible again is for the Mouse to be inside the bounds of the drawn picturebox and Left clicked.

Comment: why not try placing the control on a Panel or it's own separate panel.

Comment: I have the picturebox control placed on the panel its being drawn to, but I just cannot have it Visible. The only time I may have the control Visible is when I am dragging the control. The panel even is actaully the _MouseMove event my mistake. I guess you can say that I am trying to create my own pictureBox_MouseClick event without using a Visible picturebox. I'll add that to my original post. I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.  I added three overlapping PictureBoxes with three different background colors for testing.

Initial form setup:

```
private bool isDragging = false;
private Point dragOffset = Point.Empty;
private PictureBox dragBox;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  panel1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseDown);
  panel1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseMove);
  panel1.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseUp);
  panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel1_Paint);
  panel1.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(panel1_DragEnter);
  panel1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(panel1_DragDrop);
}
```

Drag Drop Events:

```
void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  dragBox.Location = panel1.PointToClient(
          new Point(e.X - dragOffset.X, e.Y - dragOffset.Y));
  panel1_MouseUp(null, null);
}

void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}
```

Mouse Events:

```
void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (dragBox != null && !isDragging) {
    isDragging = true;
    panel1.DoDragDrop(dragBox, DragDropEffects.Move);
  }
}

void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
    foreach (PictureBox pb in panel1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
             .OrderBy(x => panel1.Controls.GetChildIndex(x))) {

      if (pb.Bounds.Contains(e.Location)) {
        pb.BringToFront();
        pb.Visible = true;
        dragBox = pb;
        dragOffset = new Point(e.X - pb.Left, e.Y - pb.Top);
        panel1.Invalidate();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  foreach (PictureBox pb in panel1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()) {
    pb.Visible = false;
  }
  dragBox = null;
  isDragging = false;
}
```

Paint event:

```
void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  foreach (PictureBox pb in panel1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
           .OrderByDescending(x => panel1.Controls.GetChildIndex(x))) {
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(pb.BackColor), pb.Bounds);
  }
}
```

It uses `GetChildIndex` of the parent panel to get the highest PictureBox control inside the panel, and if it finds it, makes the "clicked" one visible and to the front so the Child Index is updated.

Since the PictureBoxes are always hidden (unless dragged), this code will bring the correct PictureBox to the front.  I added my paint event that draws the PictureBoxes in *reverse* order so that the highest box is painted last.

Changed the code to show the selected PictureBox on the MouseDown and then hide it again on the MouseUp.

Added drag and drop code.